# Powershell Append Headers

Tags: powershell

I'm able to pull the column names I want as my headers of my text file. They are outputted as a vertical list. I'd like them to be horizontal, tab delimited headers. Any ideas?

```
$reader=$sqlCMD.ExecuteReader()

for($i=0;$i -lt $reader.FieldCount;$i++)
{
$headers = $rdr.GetName($i) | out-file File Path Here -Append
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippet, I'm assuming that you are getting each header on either a) a new line or b) all smashed together on a single line.

Try the following, which uses string interpolation and outputs all values once at the end. (Note: that character before the t is a backtick (`` ` ``) not an apostrophe)

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++) {
    $headers = "$headers`t$($reader.GetName($i))"
}
Add-Content -Path [file-name-here] -Value $headers
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You've answered another one of my questions before, too! :)

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if you have an array (such as a list of field names) you can convert them into a single-line string using the `-join` operator:

```
PS > $fields = @()

PS > $fields+="one"

PS > $fields+="two"

PS > $fields+="three"

PS > $fields
one
two
three

PS > $fields -join "`t"
one two three
```